# Max fraction of censored values for Cox regression?

Tags: regression, convergence, censoring

I'm not sure whether there's an exact answer to this, but I'm wondering in the simplest case of doing Cox Regression with censoring on one variable, if we have N measurement values, what number (k) of them can be censored and still yield interpretable results?

In practice with MatLab, I've noted that increasing the number of censored values leads eventually to problems with the MLE converging.

Or, I suppose, another way to look at it is to ask - where is the trade-off between including censored values versus not including them?

Answer (score 2):

The critical issue is the number of events that occurred. Calculations in Cox regression are only done at event times; the censored cases (those for which an event had not happened at last follow-up) only enter the calculations in terms of the number of cases still at risk at each event time. Discarding cases that are censored would be inappropriate, as that would discard the information about the total numbers at risk. It's not clear why including censored cases (as opposed to, say, including cases with missing values of predictor variables) should lead to convergence problems.